# (js) regex match letter exclude phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to match every word that starts with an exclamation point. 
I got so far and it works. regex: ^!.
But now I wanna exclude the word "!test". So !hi matches but !test doesn't.
There's no NOT operator, so any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the regex

```js
function match(str){
    let regex = /^!(?!test)\w+/;
    return str.match(regex) != null;
}

console.log(match('!testing'))
console.log(match('!hihello'))
```

> (?!test) is a negative look ahead which ensures !test is not matched